# chrome.tabs.query() results in crashing browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chromium

i want to learn to write chrome extensions. i am not new to programming at all, but quite new to javascript and web programming.

i want to use the chrome api to iterate over all open tabs. but my code results in crashing my whole browser.
i am on debian 7.5 using chromium 34 (latest update from the debian repository)

here is my code:

```
var tabinator = {
  fillBody: function() {
    chrome.tabs.query(
      {}, 
      function(tabs) { 
        for(var i=0; i<tabs.length; i++) { 
          alert(tabs[i].id);
        }
      }
    );
  }
};

// --- Execution starts here ---
document.addEventListener(
  'DOMContentLoaded', 
  function () {
    tabinator.fillBody();
  }
);
```

i did [this tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted), and used [this reference](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs).

can anyone help.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't do alerts from popup window, as it will not work and is probably the thing crashing.

Comment: thank you this was the problem!! i just wanted to do it as simple as possible, and want to use alert() like a debug-output, ... stupid idea :(. thank you very much!!

Comment: @linluk I tried to reproduce the crash (http://pastebin.com/wksdFud0), but I'm unable to. Does the browser really crash (e.g. does it segfault?)? Can you provide the source code for the extension that causes the browser to crash (or report the bug yourself at http://crbug.com/new)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to [Xan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/934239/xan), he commented my Question an told me that i shouldn't call alert() within a popup-window. this was the problem, i now do it like this:

```
  fillBody: function() {
    chrome.tabs.query(
      {}, 
      function(tabs) { 
        for(var i=0; i<tabs.length; i++) { 
          document.write(tabs[i].title);
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Also, you can use `console.log()` and related functions; to examine that console, right-click your extension's button and select "Inspect popup".